# How to set date format to English when using a non-English language?

Tags: multilingual, date, format

After I have installed the Persian language in Joomla; now all English dates are changed to Persian dates.

How can I have the Persian language and English dates?

Answer (score 1):

You could **create a language override** for the Persian language. The Joomla documentation shows you how to do that: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Language_Overrides_in_Joomla

You could copy the following English language strings from /language/en-GB/en-GB.ini to your Persian language override:

```
DATE_FORMAT_LC="l, d F Y"
DATE_FORMAT_LC1="l, d F Y"
DATE_FORMAT_LC2="l, d F Y H:i"
DATE_FORMAT_LC3="d F Y"
DATE_FORMAT_LC4="Y-m-d"
DATE_FORMAT_LC5="Y-m-d H:i"
DATE_FORMAT_LC6="Y-m-d H:i:s"
DATE_FORMAT_JS1="y-m-d"
DATE_FORMAT_CALENDAR_DATE="%Y-%m-%d"
DATE_FORMAT_CALENDAR_DATETIME="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
DATE_FORMAT_FILTER_DATE="Y-m-d"
DATE_FORMAT_FILTER_DATETIME="Y-m-d H:i:s"
```